# slapd.d missing after installation

Tags: ldap, openldap, slapd

I am following the instructions on https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/quickstart.html to install OpenLDAP on RedHat. Everything goes fine until step 9:

> Import the configuration database
> You are now ready to import your configration database for use by slapd(8), by running the command:
>
> ```
> su root -c /usr/local/sbin/slapadd -n 0 -F /usr/local/etc/slapd.d -l /usr 
> /local/etc/openldap/slapd.ldif
> ```

Then I get the error: `su: invalid option -- 'n'`
Then I tried only running `/usr/local/sbin/slapadd -n 0 -F /usr/local/etc/slapd.d -l /usr/local/etc/openldap/slapd.ldif` since I already logged in as the root user, then I get this error:

```
 5bcca422 invalid config directory /usr/local/etc/slapd.d, error 2
 slapadd: bad configuration directory!
```

My installation prefix is the default `/usr/local/`

I find there is no `slapd.d` under `/usr/local/etc` directory. What's the problem? Thanks!

Additional Information: When I ran`make` in step 5, I got an error: `fatal error:ltdl.h: No such file or directory`, then I installed it with `yum install libtool-ltdl-devel`, and repeated step 5. When I ran make test in step 6, there is no error. I don't know if this piece of additional information could help.

Comment: RHEL already includes OpenLDAP packages. Is there a reason you are rebuilding them from source code?

Comment: @Michael Hampton Oh...I don't know that it is already in RHEL...I find slapd.d at /etc/openldap...

Answer (score 1):

The default location of configuration files is specified as build configuration option `--sysconfdir`. The default depends on value used for `--prefix`.

```
$ ./configure --help
  --sysconfdir=DIR        read-only single-machine data [PREFIX/etc]
```

So what's actually used in your case depends on the build configuration.

When starting *slapd* you can also specify the configuration to be used with command-line options `-f` for static config or `-F` for directory holding the dynamic config. This is very handy for using a local test-bed config or to stay away completely from what OS packages mess around during package installation.

The man-page *slapd(8)* locally installed on your system will show you the actual default values of your build. Bear in mind that man-pages provided by OS packages are different from your local builds from source.

Also I'd recommend **not** to use the RHEL/CentOS packages. You should use pre-built RPMs provided by [LDAP Toolbox project](https://ltb-project.org/documentation/openldap-rpm#yum_repository). They use build option `--prefix=/usr/local/openldap` and therefore dynamic config DB would be in default location */usr/local/openldap/etc/openldap/slapd.d/*.

See also: [slapd(8)](https://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapd)

Comment: Thanks. My prefix is by default /usr/local/, but I did not see slapd.d there.

Comment: `configure --prefix=/usr/local` would result in /usr/local/etc/openldap/slapd.d/ being used by default. As said in my answer: Consult the slapd(8) man-page of your local installation.

Comment: I tried  the command find usr/ -name "slapd.d", there is no slapd.d under usr/ or its subdirectories. However, I found sldap.d under /etc/openldap/.  I doubt there is created by the installation of OpenLDAP I downloaded from the official site. Can I use this sldap.d in the command to import the configuration database?

Comment: I don't know what happened on your system so far. So I can't tell which path is right. Please make sure to restart from a clean system using well-defined build options or install packages for your OS. Otherwise your results will be unpredictable.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid `su: invalid option -- 'n'` error, you can put quotes as the below:

```
su root -c '/usr/local/sbin/slapadd -n 0 -F /usr/local/etc/slapd.d -l /usr 
/local/etc/openldap/slapd.ldif'
```

Notice that I have put the part after -c inside the quotes.

As far as slapd.d is concerned, creating the directory helped me:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/etc/slapd.d
```

The cli will promptly ask for password. After that, this is what looks like on my console,

```
_#################### 100.00% eta   none elapsed            none fast!
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try:`mkdir /usr/local/etc/slapd.d`